# One-to-one relationship and deleting record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework with ASP.NET MVC3 Code First.

I have a project entity and logo like this:

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int      ProjectID   { get; set; }
    public string   Name        { get; set; }
    public string   Description { get; set; }        

    public virtual  Logo Logo   { get; set; }
}

public class Logo
{
    [Key]
    public int    LogoID          { get; set; }
    public string LogoName        { get; set; }
    public byte[] LogoContent     { get; set; }
    public string LogoContentType { get; set; }
}
```

Each project can have 0 or 1 logo attached.

When my database (sql server) is created, I see that a field is created in the table Project for referencing the logo.

[image]

Whenever I have a project in my Project table referencing a logo,I have the Logo_LogoID filled with the corresponding key in the logo table. That's ok for me. What seems strange to me is when I delete the logo, sql server show me the error below:

[image]

So in order to be able to delete a logo from my Logo table, I need first to break the reference from the Project table (by replacing the LogoID with NULL) and next delete the row from Logo.

Maybe there is a better way of referencing things?

This may seems a stupid question.

I think a better solution would be to have the inverse relation: the ProjectID field added in the Logo table. So whenever I need to delete a logo, I can easily delete the Logo.

What do you think?

Thanks.

EDIT

Like Mark Oreta suggest, I tried with:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.Logo)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

But I got a double reference to ProjectID:

[image]

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the mapping by overwriting your OnModelCreating in your DbContext with this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.Logo)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal();
    }
```

This will create a Project_ProjectID on your Logo entity.

If you want to customize the name - you said you were ok with it, but you might want to change it later, you can add this to the end:

```
.Map(m => m.MapKey("ProjectId")
```

and it will map to ProjectId on your Logo entity.

Comment: I tried with your solution. I updated my question to show result. I have a double reference to ProjectID from the Logo table??? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is the fluent mapping I put the only mapping you have?  With the code you've posted, I only have a single mapping to the Project table.

Comment: I also have a mapping defined on a User table with a Role table but nothing to do with Project and Logo.

Comment: Is the code above your actual model, can you post the entire thing?  Did CF create 2 FK relationships both pointing to Project?  If you have the ability, can you try dropping and recreating the entire DB? Its possible CF is having issues.  Maybe you should try mapping the relationship like I showed above to ProjectId, to see if you can get CF to rebuild the database properly.

Comment: I got it. Finally I do a mistake on a virtual reference from Logo. Everything works as you said. Many thanks for your patience.